# How to use a custom executor in Akka java

Tags: java, akka, dispatcher

The same question as [How to use custom executor in Akka dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029036/how-to-use-custom-executor-in-akka-dispatcher)

but in java. 
How to implement custom akka.dispatcher.ExecutorServiceConfigurator in java

Thanks